# Implement multiple file upload with Dropzone.js , Lambda and S3

Tags: php, performance, project-structure, aws, lambda

This is more a general question about this project I have on. We need to implement some UI for our costumers to upload multiple files (2000+) every month, so we can send them by email to another customers.

Now a day we have a project in PHP, reading the files locally (customers upload via FTP client) , then upload each file to aws s3 and then send them by aws ses. This solution is becoming heavy every month as we get more customers , so we need more FTP accounts and so on...

We want to update this process to a serverless solution like aws lambda , and node.js to update the lenguage tecnology.

I was thinking maybe in uploading the multiple files with dropzone.js plugin (using vue.js frontend) , to a lambda api function that save the file to S3, and then send the email via SES (maybe another separate lambda function to do that job)

I',m not an expert in Lambda and Node.js , so I was wondering what you think about this approach and maybe some ideas to improve the process? (In some point, i have to check into a mysql database to look for customer emails for each file also)

Comment: What your exact question? Architecture Reviews and coding advice are offtopic here, sorry.

Comment: You could refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39017087/hlow-to-implement-dropzone-js-to-upload-file-into-amazon-s3-server